# Авторизован ли...?

Tags: сессия, cookie, php

Скажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтоб проверял авторизован и вообще зарегистрирован ли он на сайте? Если да, то перекидываем на другую страницу. Ещё мне надо, чтоб остальные блоки, которые есть на сайте, они тоже проверялись. Вот такой код я пишу в индексе:

```
<?
include('connectdb.php'); // подключение к серверу MySql и выбор БД
$userinfo = '';
$state    = '0';
if ((isset($_COOKIE['login'])) & (isset($_COOKIE['pass']))) { // если в куках лежит логин и зашифрованый пароля
    if (!isset($_GET['exit'])) { // если кнопка выход не была нажата
        $login = $_COOKIE['login'];
        $pass  = $_COOKIE['pass'];

        // проверяем наличие пользователя в БД и достаём оттуда пароль
        $sql = "SELECT id, pass FROM users WHERE login='$login'";
        $res = mysql_query($sql);
        if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) { // если пользователь есть в БД
            $userinfo = mysql_fetch_array($res); // в этой переменной лежит пароль из БД
            if (strcmp($pass, md5($userinfo['pass'])) == 0) { //проверяем схожесть пароля из БД с паролем из куков

                // достаём все данные из БД
                $sql      = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login'";
                $res      = mysql_query($sql);
                $userinfo = mysql_fetch_array($res); // в этой переменной будет лежать вся информация о пользователе из БД
                $time     = time();
                // устанавливаем куки для запоминания статуса пользователя
                setcookie("login", $login, $time + 1800);
                setcookie("pass", $pass, $time + 1800);
                $state = 1; // статус, если 1, тогда пользователь авторизован
            }
        }
    } else {
        //обнуляем куки, если была нажата кнопка выход
        setcookie("login");
        setcookie("pass");
    }
}
if ($state != 1) { // если после проверки куков, оказалось, что пользователь не авторизован, то идем дальше
    if ((isset($_POST['login'])) & (isset($_POST['pass']))) { // если пользователь ввёл логин и пароль
        $login = $_POST['login'];

        // проверяем наличие пользователя в БД и достаём оттуда пароль
        $sql = "SELECT id, pass FROM users WHERE login='$login'";
        $res = mysql_query($sql);
        if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) { // если пользователь есть в БД
            $userinfo = mysql_fetch_array($res); // в этой переменной лежит пароль из БД и номер пользователя
            $pass     = $_POST['pass'];
            if (strcmp($pass, $userinfo['pass']) == 0) {
                // достаём все данные из БД
                $sql      = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login'";
                $res      = mysql_query($sql);
                $userinfo = mysql_fetch_array($res); // в этой переменной будет лежать вся информация о пользователе из БД
                $time     = time();
                // устанавливаем куки для запоминания статуса пользователя, пароль шифруем
                setcookie("login", $login, $time + 1800);
                setcookie("pass", md5($pass), $time + 1800);
                $state = 1; // статус, если 1, тогда пользователь авторизован
            }
        }
    }
}
if ($state != 1) {
    include_once("/blocks/autoriz.php");
} else {
?>
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
    </head>

    <body>
    <table width="912" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col"><?php include("blocks/header.php"); ?></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="155"><?php include("blocks/sidebar.php"); ?></td>
        <td width="800">{</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><?php include("blocks/footer.php"); ?></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: @Саша Осипов, маленькая просьба: почистите ваш код, у вас тут и футер вставляется, который к вопросу отношения не имеет!

Comment: Плохая идея хранить, пароль в куках, очень плохая. А голым md5 уже никого не напугать.
Почитайте про сессии, и вообще полистайте php.net и прочие ресурсы.

[http://php.net/manual/ru/features.sessions.php][1]


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/features.sessions.php

Не используйте нативный mysql_*, есть хорошие расширения: PDO, MySQLi etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Алгоритм примерно такой:

1. При автроизации\регистрации пользователя сохраняешь логин и метку об авторизации и случайное число, которое хранится и в базе и в куках.
2. Создаёшь файл, например firewall.php
3. В этом файле реализуешь проверку в базе: есть ли пользователь с таким логином в базе. Проверяешь случайное число на соответсвие (канешн ооочень примитивно, но для примера). Если не сходятся данные, то на страницу логина.
4. Так же там реализуешь функцию проверку прав.
5. В основном скрипте:

   ```
   include('firewall.php'); // Автоматом проверяет авторизацию пользователя, если   //нет - то на стр. авторизации.
   // Далее код выполняется, только если пользователь авторизован, и в $role хранится //id

   //роли пользователя.
   if( check_access( 'this_page', $role ){ // this-page - id страницы, check_access

   //проверяет возможность доступа юзера с правами $role для данной страницы.
   ```

Это вариант для контроля доступа на основе ролей. Более сложный вариант - ACL, который позволяет проверить доступ конкретного пользователя к конкретному объекту.